# PHP Print statement works only in Firefox

Tags: php, drupal, firefox

The site is built in drupal. The following code calls some data for the page:

```
<span class="bold caps">Length: </span><?php print $node->field_length[0]['view'];?>
```

The right information shows up when viewing the page in Firefox but that's it. Chrome, IE & Safari are all missing the info. The rendered HTML is fine but for the lack of the right data coming through.

Here is a [link to the page in question](http://msvehicles.com/gsa/mobile-mammography-clinic-msv-m-4000-102-40-b)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't randomly decide to NOT output something based on the browser that's requesting the page. The choice of browser can NOT affect how PHP runs a piece of code. However, the choice of browser CAN affect the data that is sent to the script as input, which can affect how the script runs.

So check what the differences are between what FF sends to your script against what the other browsers are sending.

Comment: You are right of course. It turned out to be a permission issue based on login. I was logged in under FF and not the other browsers. I just had to adjust the permissions for the fields in question in order to get them to show up. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a server-side thing, not a client side. It SHOULD show in all browsers

1) Check the page source of Firefox and Opera/Safari/Chrome - the string might exist in all of them but due to rendering engine differences only show up in Firefox - then it's CSS/HTML issue

2) I don't see it in Firefox 6 (even in the source). I suspect it might be a SESSION thing. For example $node->field_length[0]['view'] is empty if you are missing something in your browser session. So for example you have active session with Firefox but because you haven't logged in with the other browsers - it doesn't show up.

Those are just guesses, without seeing more server side code.

Comment: You were spot on. When you add new fields to a node in Drupal you HAVE to remember to grant permissions to users so that they can see the data contained in those fields. It was a total Noob error on my part. Thanks for reminding me about the session issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you view source in each browser you should find that the source looks exactly the same in every browser.

Here are the validation errors on your page.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmsvehicles.com%2Fgsa%2Fmobile-mammography-clinic-msv-m-4000-102-40-b&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Fix all of these and your problem will probably fix itself.

Comment: The validation errors sometimes crop up because of the Drupal engine. I will look those over to make sure none are coming from the theme I created for the site. Thanks for looking at the problem for me.